# Aplicativos Híbridos: quando utilizar e qual a necessidade?

Tags: mobile, framework, xamarin, ionic

Com Aplicações híbridas `cross-platform` ganhamos tempo de desenvolvimento, mas tenho algumas dúvidas quanto a verdadeira necessidade de utilizar um framework.

Os mais famosos **PhoneGap**, **Ionic** e **Titanium** são fáceis e amigáveis. Mas devido ao fato de ser em `HTML`, `CSS` e `JavaScript` creio que as aplicações dependem de um navegador. Pelo que entendi, são emuladas. Ocorre que ainda não fiz o teste em várias plataformas, com isso surgiu algumas dúvidas:

1. O código é reutilizável ou é único para sistemas como Android e IOS?
2. Quando devo utilizar esse tipo de framework? Com ele poderei fazer aplicativos robustos que irá utilizar o máximo do aparelho?
3. Poderei modificar o layout de um sistema específico ou todos os sistemas irão usar os mesmos recursos?

Por outro lado vejo, em constante crescimento, o **Xamarin**. Em análise, percebi que ele funciona diferente dos outros framework's. Pude perceber também que o código é reutilizado em várias plataformas, gerando um aplicativo nativo.

Mais dúvidas surgiram:

1. Com ele poderei fazer `build` para Android, IOS e WP na mesma IDE?
2. Quanto de código posso reaproveitar para plataformas diferentes?
3. Ainda irei depender do MAC para fazer testes e publicar meus aplicativos?

Para artigo de pesquisa, sugiro deixar também, além das perguntas, uma lista de pós e contras de cada framework.

Comment: Penso que `Xamarin` não se enquadra como hibrido, pois todos os componentes e acesso ao dispositivo são nativos.

Comment: O desenvolvimento para todas as plataformas é com `c#` correto?

Comment: Isso mesmo, C#. Definição [Hibrido](http://www.devmedia.com.br/como-criar-aplicativos-mobile-hibridos-e-offline/32361)

Comment: Você saberia responder todas as perguntas do post? Me ajudaria muito.

Comment: Já desenvolvi (pouco) aplicativos híbridos se o que busca é performance pode esquecer, pode ter problema de compatibilidade (layout, comandos, etc), não que nativo não tenha, mas hibrido é extremamente pior. `Xamarin FORMS` o aproveitamento chega a 99%, sendo que pode chegar a 100% facilmente se não tiver algo muito específico para cada plataforma. Para desenvolver iOS vai precisar MAC ou Virtualizar um (HACKINTOSH). Para WP vai precisar de WIN8 ou superior.

Comment: @HStackOverflow, você sabe dizer em questão de compatibilidade quais celulares não dão suporte?

Comment: Xamarin gera nativo portanto não tem problema com relação a compatibilidade relativo a **modelo** de celular. Obviamente a compatibilidade será com relação a versão do `Android` instalado no aparelho. Especificamente `Xamarin Forms` é compatível com a versão 4.0 ou superior, salvo engano.

Comment: O @Fernando fez uma pesquisa e montou um artigo sobre desenvolvimento para dispositivos móveis. Ele aparece no chat quase que diariamente.. deixe uma msg pra ele lá.

Comment: @emanuelsn Você não tem o artigo?

Comment: Acho que sim. Na hora do almoço eu confirmo e te notifico aqui.

Comment: Esse é o artigo. [LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1dnvcb1mks1R1V0R05vUHdrLXM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: O mais recomendado é criar um projeto html, css e javascript e depois criar os apps com as IDES de cada plataforma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos por cada pergunta:

1) O código é reutilizável ou é único para sistemas como Android e IOS?
Quando devo utilizar esse tipo de framework?

Boa parte do código poderá ser reutilizada para todas as plataformas, mas tudo aquilo que fizer acesso nativo ao sistema utilizará uma API em JS para fazer acesso a um recurso do aparelho, como câmera, armazenamento ou GPS, terá um código específico para cada plataforma.
  Fora isso, seu código irá rodar dentro de uma WebView, que é um browser nativo do SO que irá garantir acesso a recursos do SO rodando seu site. O desempenho do seu app assim vai depender da capacidade da WebView. Elas estão evoluindo muito e hoje permitem uma performance muito boa mesmo comparado a um app nativo.

2) Com ele poderei fazer aplicativos robustos que irá utilizar o máximo do aparelho?

Se não me engano iOS e Android permitem acesso a todas as APIs pela WebView, mas a performance depende muito mais das tecnologias Web do que disso, por exemplo, para fazer jogos você pode usar o WebGL, que evoluiu bastante não possui tantas bibliotecas ou capacidades como as opções nativas.

3) Poderei modificar o layout de um sistema específico ou todos os sistemas irão usar os mesmos recursos?

Isso depende unicamente de você. Você pode usar JavaScript para controlar dinamicamente o que vai ser disponibilizado ou já gerar o código sem ou com opções para os builds de cada SO.

Com relação ao Xamarin, não conheço quase nada para opinar.

Minha dica para você é a seguinte: faça uma aplicação Web que poderia facilmente ser adaptada para Mobile, faça alguns testes e vá testando sua ideia. Caso você realmente precise de um app, considere fazer um nativo caso ele não precise de tanto processamento e performance.